# Can I substitute duck breast for leg?

Tags: substitutions, duck

I managed to pick up a couple of duck breasts that were on offer.  I had a nice meal recently that included duck breast served on duck hash.

The recipe for this meal involves jointing a whole duck, serving the breast on top of the hash in which the shredded duck leg meat is mixed with potato and onion.

As I have 2 breasts and I only need one, so can I simply substitute a breast for the leg meat or will the breast have the wrong texture or other shortcoming?

Comment: I'm morally opposed to this question.  It's equivalent to "I'm out of hamburger. Can I just grind up this Kobe Beef filet instead?"

Answer (score 1):

Like poultry, duck has fatter legs than breasts and also the meat itself is darker, adding a different flavor to the meal.
The fat in the legs will melt and the potatoes and onions will cook in it.

It would be great if you had some duck fat to add to the breasts or at least any kind of fat, for the flavor.
But if you like to eat learn unfatty meals, you can stick with the breast only.

Comment: The breasts still have the skin on, so there is a decent layer of fat on there.  I'll try roasting to medium-rare then adding to the hash. Thanks